# how to check if object of a class already exists in PHP?

Tags: php

consider the following code scenario:

```
<?php

//widgetfactory.class.php
// define a class
class WidgetFactory
{
  var $oink = 'moo';
}

?>


<?php

//this is index.php
include_once('widgetfactory.class.php');

// create a new object
//before creating object make sure that it already doesn't exist

if(!isset($WF))
{
$WF = new WidgetFactory();
}

?>
```

The widgetfactory class is in widgetfactoryclass.php file,  I have included this file in my index.php file, all my site actions runs through index.php, i.e. for each action this file gets included, now I want to create object of widgetfactory class ONLY if already it doesn't exist. I am using `isset()` for this purpose, is there any other better alternative for this?

Comment: This is a 'singleton': http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php  (see example #2)

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: @j08691 I guess class_exist() wont help this case, as I want to check wheather the object exists or not and not the class

Comment: Could be helpful http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

Comment: I am now looking for almost exactly the same thing. Anyone any more recent methods for achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using globals *might* be a way to achieve this. The common way to do this are singleton instances:

```
class WidgetFactory {
   private static $instance = NULL;

   static public function getInstance()
   {
      if (self::$instance === NULL)
         self::$instance = new WidgetFactory();
      return self::$instance;
   }

   /*
    * Protected CTOR
    */
   protected function __construct()
   {
   }
}
```

Then, later on, instead of checking for a global variable `$WF`, you can retrieve the instance like this:

```
$WF = WidgetFactory::getInstance();
```

The constructor of `WidgetFactory` is declared `protected` to ensure instances can only be created by `WidgetFactory` itself.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the job:

```
if ( ($obj instanceof MyClass) != true ) {
    $obj = new MyClass();
}
```